# Get current Image width and height after max-width and max-height are applied

Tags: jquery, html, css

Here is [my example](http://jsfiddle.net/RedKnight91/HSsqc/1/)

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/500x500" alt="500x500" />
</div>
<div class="container">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100x500" alt="100x500" />
</div>
<div class="container">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/500x100" alt="500x100" />
</div>
<div class="container">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/500x800" alt="500x800" />
</div>
<div class="container">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/800x500" alt="800x500" />
</div>
<div class="container">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="100x100" />
</div>
<div class="container">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x100" alt="200x100" />
</div>​
```

CSS:

```
div.container { width: 200px; height: 200px; line-height: 200px; overflow: hidden; border: 10px solid white; box-shadow: 0 1px 8px #BBB; margin: 10px; text-align: center; }
            div.container img { position: relative; vertical-align:middle; }
            div.container img.wide { max-height: 100%; }
            div.container img.tall { max-width: 100%; }
            div.container img.square { max-width: 100%; }​
```

Javascript:

```
$(window).load( function(){
var $imgs = $("div.container img");

$imgs.each( function(){
    var cW = $(this).parent().width();
    var cH = $(this).parent().height();
    var w = $(this).width(); //I want the CURRENT width, not original!!
    var h = $(this).height(); //I want the CURRENT height, not original!!
    var dW = w - cW;
    var dH = h - cH;

    console.log( cW + " " + cH + " " + w + " " + h + " " + dW + " " + dH );

    if ( w > h ){ 
        $(this).addClass("wide");
        $(this).css("left",  -dW/2);
    }
    else if ( w < h ){
        $(this).addClass("tall");
        $(this).css("top",  -dH/2);
    }
    else { $(this).addClass("square"); }                    
});
});​
```

I'm adding, via javascript, a class to the image elements based on their proportions. The 3 classes will set the max-width and max-height css properties for the images, thus resizing them.
After that, I need the resized image's dimensions, but all I can get is the original image's dimensions. That's no good! I tried using `width()`, `outerWidth`, `naturalWidth`, every kind of width, but I just can't get it right.

So, is there a way to get the image's dimensions after CSS rules like `max-width` and `max-height` have been applied to it? Preferably a consistent way, not using timers and intervals, or stuff like that.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: `width()` does give you the current width... http://jsfiddle.net/mYZVR/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out [this](http://jsfiddle.net/HSsqc/2/) jsfiddle. You are trying to get widht/height BEFORE you apply a class with `max-height`/`max-width` instead of after it is applied.

Here is test code (check second console.log):

```
$(window).load( function(){
    var $imgs = $("div.container img");

    $imgs.each( function(){
        var cW = $(this).parent().width();
        var cH = $(this).parent().height();
        var w = $(this)[0].clientWidth; //I want the CURRENT width, not original!!
        var h = $(this)[0].clientHeight; //I want the CURRENT height, not original!!
        var dW = w - cW;
        var dH = h - cH;

        console.log( cW + " " + cH + " " + w + " " + h + " " + dW + " " + dH );

        if ( w > h ){ 
            $(this).addClass("wide");
            $(this).css("left",  -dW/2);
        }
        else if ( w < h ){
            $(this).addClass("tall");
            $(this).css("top",  -dH/2);
        }
        else { $(this).addClass("square"); }     
        var w = $(this).width(); //I want the CURRENT width, not original!!
        var h = $(this).height(); //I want the CURRENT height, not original!!
        console.log( w + " " + h );

    });
});​
```

`width()`, `outerWidth` - this always return current width.

`naturalWidth`/[`naturalHeight`](http://help.dottoro.com/ljqqtiks.php) - this is to get an original,like with no any styles applied, width/height of image (available for IMG tag only in newer browsers)

Comment: Ooooooooh shh..... damn, it was so easy!! Sorry for bothering you man, I totally didn't notice.. hahahaha!